# How to check whether an int input is greater than 2147436647 or smaller than -2147483648?

Tags: c, int

Doing this :

```
int nbr;
if (nbr <= -2147483648 || nbr >= 2147483647)
    printf("No way !!");
```

Does not write No Way !! for value under the lower limit (for example -2147483650) because the inputs numbers become positive !!

Comment: How did you input the numbers?

Comment: What function are you using for input? Assuming a 32-bit system, an `int` simply cannot hold a value outside that range. And if you use one of the `scanf` functions it has no way to check for numeric overflow.

Comment: Use a long long since it guarantees it can hold outside of that range, check if it goes over the limits of an Integer, then cast it back for your computation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `long long` type instead of `int`.  That will (probably) give you a 64bit integer unless your compiler is old. Use %lld if you are using `scanf`.

Comment: best to use `int64_t`, not all platforms do things the same way

Comment: @MarkYisri Note that while `int64_t` is extremely commonly implemented - and very useful, a C99/C11 compliant compiler need not provide that _optional_ type - not all platforms support that.  (C11 7.20.1.1 3). All C99/C11 compliant compilers supply `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

`int` will only exceed the range  [-2147436647 2147483647] on platforms with wider than 32-bit `int`.

```
#include <limits.h>

int nbr;
#if INT_MIN < -2147483648 || INT_MAX >= 2147483647
if (nbr < -2147483648 || nbr > 2147483647)
    printf("No way !!");
#endif
```

Pre C99 platform may need work to handle `-2147483648`.

---

To detect if a string converted to `long` will exceed its range,

```
char buf[100];
buf[0] = 0;
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

errno = 0;
char *endptr;
long x = strtol(buf, &endtr, 10);
if (buf == endptr) puts("No conversion");
else if (errno) puts("Out of long range");

// If `long` is wider than 32-bit and  [-2147483648 2147483647] range still needed
else if (x < -2147483648 || x > 2147483647) puts("No way !!");

else printf("%ld\n", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see if an int is outside its range because it can't even hold a value outside its range.